# Correct way to ask the carrier when your package will be shipped

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say **"Do you know when the package is expected to be shipped?"**?
What about **When is the expected date for the package to be shipped?**
Are there other ways to say this?

What is "is+past tense" (**is expected**) called?

Comment: It's not "is+past tense". It is **is + past participle** and here it expresses the _passive voice_ of the verb _expect_ in the _simple present_ tense.

Comment: I'd probably say it more simply: _"Do you know when the package will ship?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you know when the package is expected to be shipped?
>
> When is the expected date for the package to be shipped?

Both of these are acceptable.  The term you're looking for, I think, is *passive voice* since "is expected" and "to be shipped" are in the *passive* form of the verbs "to expect" and "to ship":

> They expect that I will ship the package
>
> It is expected (by them) that the package will be shipped (by me)

To answer your question about other ways to say this, the passive form of the verb sounds somewhat more *polite* than the active form.  If you don't care about politeness, you can use the active voice:

> Do you know when you expect to ship the package?
>
> What is the expected date you will ship the package?

or even more direct:

> When are you going to ship the package?

There are, of course, many other verbs you can use to express the same concept:

> When do you plan to mail me the package?
>
> When do you think you will deliver the package?
>
> When do you anticipate the package will arrive?

And so on.

Final note:  In your second sentence "expected" is not the past tense of "to expect".  It's the adjective form of "expect" that modifies the noun "date": "the expected date"

Comment: Is it **when** is the expected date for the package to be shipped?, **what** is the expected date for the package to be shipped?, or either one?

Comment: Usually, "what date will it be shipped?" or, "when will it be shipped?" but it's not unusual for people to say, "when is the date..?"